# Angular 2 plunker not working

Tags: angular

I created a new Angular 2 plunk using default setup in plunker. after that I created a component in separate folder name JokeComponent with two files .ts and .html and also declared it in app.ts. since it is bootstrapping the application. Used the custom tag name  in app component. But now it is not working.

Please help to run this application

```
`https://plnkr.co/edit/2IJdAfW6zNDDDv4GRivB`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JokeComponent` is not under src, so this path is not working:

```
import {JokeComponent} from './joke/jokeComponent'
```

I've moved it under src and changed the html path accordingly

Fixed plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/gWgaJWMLfxqbHEdJQGh2?p=preview

Comment: Thank You @echonax

Comment: It is still not working...it gives 54 error in console..can you please find the reason

Comment: @eko : Fixed plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/gWgaJWMLfxqbHEdJQGh2?p=preview no longer working

Comment: @eko As of today following both answers and visiting the Punkers that are mentioned does not helps, the Plunker still doesn't work. Any other thing that I may be missing?

Comment: @devGeek why do you want to use this particular plunker?

Answer (score 1):

I used to have that error with all my Angular 2+ plunker projects, the problem was with the zone.js 0.8.13. and reverting to 0.8.12 does it for now

In the index I changed

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.12/dist/zone.js"></script>
```

With that your [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CkQAfH4oz3rjx4DrSQY3?p=preview)  is working.

According to https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/832 the error happens only in zone.js version 0.8.13 and It happens when you do Event binding.